# CSS Maintain Shape/Size of Diagonal Background Image on Text

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-gradients

You can see what I am trying to implement here: http://jsfiddle.net/j1234cl/e8nxrnw4/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfourteen-style-css'  href="style.css" type='text/css' media='all' />
<title>Background Image</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="content-section">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
                </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.content-section {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/vcA64hy.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 98% 100% transparent;
    padding: 55px 30px 0px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px;
    min-height: 230px;
}
```

I am trying to implement a striped, diagonal background image behind my text content. I want the image to also cut off in the bottom right hand corner however I am having trouble implementing it so that the looks like the same (grey lines are the same size and the gaps between the lines are the same size) no matter how much content is on the page and where the image cuts off in the bottom right the angle of the cut off line is always the same.

I am currently using a background image but am wondering if the effect should be implemented using a CSS gradient however in the image not only is there the stripe effect there is also a gradient within it.

Any tips on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is achievable using multiple CSS Gradients layered on top of each other.

I've set this to the body but it can be used on nearly any element.

It will not distort from the design or style and will continuously repeat so should be exactly what you require.

```css
body {
  background:
    /* white to transparent*/
    linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%),
    /* thin line from top right */
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff, #fff 2px, #ddd 2px, #ddd 4px);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
<p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p>
```

- [CSS Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)
- [Using CSS Gradients | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients)